# Topology and protocol for boards connection

Tags: i2c, bus, protocol, topology

Would like to have some insight on which data protocol to use to communicate between a master and several slave boards on a project i'm working on.

My initial idea was to daisy chain all the slaves. Each having one input RJ45 connector (data+power) and another output RJ45 (data+power) for the next device in the chain. The data protocol being I2C. I would then use ethernet cables (2 pairs for data + 2pair for power) to connect the boards.

Something like this:
[image]

The slave boards will be very simple, containing only some GPIO expanders (MCP23017, I2C or SPI). And I want to avoid having to add a microcontroller to each slave for simplicity and mainly because of the current chip shortage.
Also, each board will be a maximum of about 1 meter apart.

My concern with this setup is the reliability of I2C at this cable length. I also thought of converting the I2C bus on each slave to a differential signal like CAN or RS485, but this will had additional circuitry (maybe even a microcontroller) which I'm trying to avoid.
I would appreciate any input.

Comment: (1) Is the single boutique IC MCP23017/S17 more readily available than some MCU from a wide array of available MCUs? May be. I just wouldn't have guessed it would be. (And you don't need the MCP23xxx if you use an MCU, instead.) (2) The I2C can be run pretty slow. 100 kHz, for example. What speeds are you needing to deal with, exactly? (3) And is this a quiet environment? Differential drivers are nice but RS-232 signalling does also provide some noise immunity despite being single-ended. (4) Have you just experimented with simple twisted pair CAT-6 or the like?

Comment: I2C is intended for devices on the same PCB and is not well suited to comms on any significant length of cable.  The same applies to SPI except that the signals are all unidirectional (I2C uses the data and in some cases the clock in both directions) and so SPI could be used with line drivers.  I would be cautious about running a large number of devices in series though because of the cumulative delays.

Comment: @jonk 
1) In my case, yes. As I have stock of a few dozen of them from a previous project.
2) I'm not really sure about the speed I need. The slave board will connect to some switches, LEDs and some additional I2C controlled encoders which will be controlled by a user. So I'm guessing 100 kHz would suffice.
3) Yes, no noisy components nearby.
4) I didn't experiment at all. Are you suggesting experiment with the layout I described?

Comment: @Frog  I'm aware of that, that's why I'm a bit worried about the reliability of the system and thought of using differential drivers. But I've also seen cases of users successfully using I2C over a few meters.

Comment: @Fperola it’s possible certainly but whether it will be reliable is another matter.  You’ll need to consider where to put your pull-up resistors - just at one end will be very prone to noise, both ends would be better if that’s feasible, each node would be possible if you know that the number of nodes won’t change (or not much).

Comment: You say a meter between slaves, but how may slaves or how long bus it will be in total? I2C can be used for several meters without special tricks, but only if properly designed.

Answer (score 1):

We've used level-translating I2C bus repeaters for connecting multiple power supplies together.  They have active current sources instead of passive pull-up resistors and can support typically ~400pF of capacitance on either side of the bus which is several meters of Cat5e cable.  There are specialized interface chips that will make it into a differential link but the repeaters are going to be easier to find since they're used for HDMI links.

Comment: That seems to be what I need. Do you recommend any specific part? In a quick search I found this PCA9515A which seems to fit. I would then add one of these to each slave, right?

Comment: Yep, those are what we use.  You *should* be able to get away with using it just on the main board.  They cannot be connected in a port A to port A configuration because the current sources interfere with each other, but you can daisy chain port A to port B.  This will allow several meters of cable between each device at the expense of a few hundred ns of propagation delay.

Comment: Got that backwards; you can connect port A on multiple devices together; port B can't be connected to another port B.  You still should be able to just use one device on port A for a few m, but they can be connected together to possibly extend range and of course if you need the level shifting capability.

Comment: I don't think repeaters such as PCA9515A is used for HDMI links or daisy chaina. As you can't put two PCA9515A chips in a chain (it says so in the datasheet) so you can't put one on your device, if someone else has already put one on the other device. Having this kind of buffer would likely cause a fail in official HDMI testing.